# I've written a simple program to automate the Fibonacci sequence and it's not working and I can't figure out why

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

I'm trying to get a better understanding of functions in python and decided to try automating the Fibonacci sequence. This is my code so far and it's not doing what it's supposed to. I can't figure out why it's not working. Can someone please point my errors out?

I'm using the stop variable as a definite stop and the length variable telling the program how far I'd like it to execute the code. Below is my code:

```
length = 6
stop = 10

def append_sum(lst):
    while length <= stop:
        return lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])

print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

Comment: "it's not doing what it's supposed to" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: When I run the code I just get "None" displayed. I have looked at other examples but I'm wondering why my code isn't adding the sum of the last two elements and adding it to the list. @JörgWMittag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length variable in your code doesn't change, so the stop doesn't work because of that. Also even if it did, you return the list after it enters the while function, so at most it will do one iteration.
lst.append() will mutate the list, but won't return a copy of it so , you can't return lst.append()

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I would just Google it.

```
a = int(input('Give amount: '))

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(list(fib(a)))
```

Result:

```
Give amount: 10
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```